# Filling a data.table from smaller data.tables

Tags: r, data.table, copy, fill

I am looking for a way to fill a *Result* data.table from smaller data.tables that come from calculations.
My approach was the following:

```
#CREATE EXAMPLE

library(data.table)

# The empty table to be filled

DT <- data.table(
   "ID" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
   "A" = numeric(4),
   "B" = numeric(4))

   ID A B
1:  a 0 0
2:  b 0 0
3:  c 0 0
4:  d 0 0

# Table with part of the results
DT_short <- data.table(
         "ID" = c("a", "b", "d"),
         "A" = 1:3,
         "B" = 1:3)

   ID A B
1:  a 1 1
2:  b 2 2
3:  d 3 3
```

What I would like to do is to fill rows and columns according to their name.
I managed to access the part of the big data.table I want to change by

```
nm1 <- names(DT_short)
DT[ID %in% DT_short[, ID], ..nm1]
#Bonus question: Why do I have to assign nm1 before, how do I make it work directly in []?
```

Now I would like to replace this part of `DT` by the small table `DT_short`, but everything I tried (like `<-` or `:=`, or some kind of `merge`) didn't work. E.g. error `object '..nm1' not found` for `DT[ID %in% DT_short[, ID], ..nm1] <- DT_short`

Please help me by providing a solution or pointing me in the right direction. (Since the data I am working with is rather small - 10^2 columns, 10^2 rows, ~40 small files to be combined, number<10^9 per field - and other people will use my code readability is more important than performance.)

**EDIT**

In response to Ronak Shah. When I test your solution with the code below it works perfectly well without any errors/warnings. Before accepting the solution I would like to make sure it works for others as well / know why it causes warnings for you and not me.

```
library(data.table)
packageVersion('data.table')
#[1] ‘1.12.8’

#the empty table to be filled
DT <- data.table(
  "ID" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  "A" = numeric(4),
  "B" = numeric(4),
  "C" = numeric(4)
)
#   ID A B C
#1:  a 0 0 0
#2:  b 0 0 0
#3:  c 0 0 0
#4:  d 0 0 0

#table with part of the results
DT_short <- data.table(
  "ID" = c("a", "b", "d"),
  "A" = 1:3,
  "B" = 1:3
)
#   ID A B
#1:  a 1 1
#2:  b 2 2
#3:  d 3 3

#table with part of the results 2
DT_shorter <- data.table(
  "ID" = c("c"),
  "A" = 7,
  "B" = 70,
  "C" = 3.14
)
#   ID A  B    C
#1:  c 7 70 3.14


DT[match(DT_short$ID, DT$ID), match(names(DT_short), names(DT))] <- DT_short
DT[match(DT_shorter$ID, DT$ID), match(names(DT_shorter), names(DT))] <- DT_shorter
DT
#   ID A  B    C
#1:  a 1  1 0.00
#2:  b 2  2 0.00
#3:  c 7 70 3.14
#4:  d 3  3 0.00
```

Comment: It seems that you want to merge (join) the two data.table objects?

Comment: As far as I understand the merge function adds additional columns to the table, but I want to replace them. Instead of columns A.x, A.y I just want to have one column A that gets the values from the respective column in the other table.
If there is a way to achieve that with merge, that'd be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you are ok with other solutions, this part is easy to do with base R data.frames by subsetting row and columns of smaller dataframes from the bigger ones and assigning the shorter dataframe.

```
df1 <- data.frame(DT)
df2 <- data.frame(DT_short)
df1[match(df2$ID, df1$ID), match(names(df2), names(df1))] <- df2

df1
#  ID A B
#1  a 1 1
#2  b 2 2
#3  c 0 0
#4  d 3 3
```

---

I don't think it is right to do the same with `data.table` but if we run the above code it works (atleast for the example shared)

```
DT[match(DT_short$ID, DT$ID), match(names(DT_short), names(DT))] <- DT_short
```

but it returns a big warning message which kind of confirms this isn't the right approach for data.tables.

Comment: Would you share the warning message you got? When I ran your code it actually worked perfectly fine without any warnings/errors.

Additionally to the empty table above I have tested with:

`#table with part of the results
DT_short <- data.table(
  "ID" = c("a", "b", "d"),
  "A" = 1:3,
  "B" = 1:3
)

#table with part of the results 2
DT_shorter <- data.table(
  "ID" = c("c"),
  "A" = 7,
  "B" = 70
)


DT[match(DT_short$ID, DT$ID), match(names(DT_short), names(DT))] <- DT_short
DT[match(DT_shorter$ID, DT$ID), match(names(DT_shorter), names(DT))] <- DT_shorter
DT`

Comment: @JanW Yes, I get the expected output as well but with a warning message which reads `1: In \`[<-.data.table\`(\`*tmp*\`, match(DT_short$ID, DT$ID), match(names(DT_short),  :
  Coerced integer RHS to double to match the type of the target column (column 2 named 'A'). If the target column's type double is correct, it's best for efficiency to avoid the coercion and create the RHS as type double. To achieve that consider R's type postfix: typeof(0L) vs typeof(0), and typeof(NA) vs typeof(NA_integer_).....` My `data.table` version  is `packageVersion('data.table')` `#[1] ‘1.12.2’`

Comment: I will edit my question to include a complete example in a moment. I have version `packageVersion('data.table')` `[1] ‘1.12.8’`

Comment: @JanW As far as your update is concerned it works for me without a warning with `DT_shorter` (don't know why).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach. For each column in `mycols`, you want to assign values from `DT_short`. When you do that, you want to use `match()` and get indices, and use it to create a new vector. Once you create a new data.table, you want to replace NAs with 0.

```
library(data.table)

mycols <- names(DT)[2:3]

as.data.table(lapply(mycols, function(x){
    DT_short[match(x = DT$ID, table = DT_short$ID), ..x]}))[,
      (mycols) := replace(x = .SD, list = is.na(.SD), values = 0),
      .SDcols = mycols][]

#   A B
#1: 1 1
#2: 2 2
#3: 0 0
#4: 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However replacing NAs with 0 is problematic, since I have multiple files to combine. When I do this for the second small table it overrides all data from the first one with 0.
What I need is to replace NAs with values from DT.

By the way, I'm open for solutions in dplyr or any other popular R package if you can think of any.

Comment: @JanW Can you create a sample data that reflects your real situation?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Ronak provided a nice solution - in case you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an update join:

```
cols <- setdiff(names(DT_short), "ID")
DT[DT_short, on=.(ID), (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols))]
```

Comment: This works fine. I'll definitely look into update joins. However Ronaks solution runs twice as fast for me.

Comment: yup for 100 rows and 100 columns, base R will be faster